# Does "-workers:1" prevent parallelization in nunit3-console when running multiple test assemblies?

Tags: parallel-processing, nunit, nunit-console

I need to ensure that NUnit runs tests sequentially even when running multiple test assemblies so I am using a command line like:

```
nunit3-console.exe -workers:1 testAssembly1.dll testAssembly2.dll testAssembly3.dll
```

But tests are still running in parallel. If I run it only on 1 DLL at a time I get only 1 worker.

So now I am thinking that `-workers:1` limits how many workers can run in parallel within the same DLL, but does not limit how many DLLs can run in parallel. But I can't find anything in the documentation explicitly saying so.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--workers` limits the number of worker threads available - which controls how many of your tests *within each assembly* run in parallel. (Relevant to your use of Parallelizable attribute - i.e. if you haven't used Parallelizable, you can leave `--workers` to the default!)

To restrict different assemblies running in parallel, you need the `--agents` option.